# Tikz - help me clean up this figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like the w_{n-1} label to show up below the line, and to have the $\vodts$ be spaced more clearly. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes, automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,>=stealth',thick, thresh/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
    \node[thresh] (1) {$\theta$};
    \coordinate[left of=1] (d2);
    \coordinate[below of=d2] (invis);
    \coordinate[above of=d2] (d1);
    \coordinate[below of=d2] (d3);
    \coordinate[right of=1] (outer);
    \draw [->] (1) to[in=60,out=90,loop] node[auto] {$w_n$} (1);
    \draw [->] (invis) to node[auto] {$\vdots$} (1);
    \draw [->] (d1) to[] node[auto] {$w_1$} (1);
    \draw [->] (d2) to node[auto] {$w_2$} (1);
    \draw [->] (d3) to node[in=260] {$w_{n-1}$} (1);
    \draw [->] (1) to node[auto] {$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$} ++ (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 4):

What about this? (no need for the `invis` auxiliar coordinate)

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes, automata,calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,>=stealth',thick, thresh/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
    \node[thresh] (1) {$\theta$};
    \coordinate[left of=1] (d2);
    \coordinate[above of=d2] (d1);
    \coordinate[below of=d2] (d3);
    \coordinate[right of=1] (outer);
    \draw [->] (1) to[in=60,out=90,loop] node[auto] {$w_n$} (1);
    \draw [->] (d1) to[] node[auto] {$w_1$} (1);
    \draw [->] (d2) to node[auto] (w2) {$w_2$} (1);
    \draw [->] (d3) to node[yshift=-1em,below] (wn1) {$w_{n-1}$} (1);
    \draw [->] (1) to node[auto] {$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$} ++ (3,0);

    % now the dots
    \foreach \i in {0.5, 0.6, 0.7} 
      \node at ($(wn1)!\i!(w2)$) {.};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image: Result]